# How to Get Name of Next Junction(Road) from My location using GeoCoding

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Right now I m getting all information Like Current Address, country name,postal code etc Using Geo Coding from my Location Through GPS, but I want to get the name of next Junction(Road) or next address from my GPS position using geo coding `String s = "Address Line: "
                                + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + "\n"
                                + addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + "\n"
                                + "Locality: "
                                + addresses.get(0).getLocality() + "\n"
                                + addresses.get(0).getPremises() + "\n"
                                + "Admin Area: "
                                + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + "\n"
                                + "Country code: "
                                + addresses.get(0).getCountryCode() + "\n"
                                + "Country name: "
                                + addresses.get(0).getCountryName() + "\n"
                                + "Phone: " + addresses.get(0).getPhone()
                                + "\n" + "Postbox: "
                                + addresses.get(0).getPostalCode() + "\n"
                                + "SubLocality: "
                                + addresses.get(0).getSubLocality() + "\n"
                                + "SubAdminArea: "
                                + addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea() + "\n"
                                + "SubThoroughfare: "
                                + addresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare()
                                + "\n" + "Thoroughfare: "
                                + addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() + "\n"
                                + "URL: " + addresses.get(0).getUrl();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your request returns more than one JSON objects, you can retrieve the next result or in your specific case, the next supposed junction, by just incrementing the index. Much like how you access arrays.

> Example
>
> ```
> addresses.get(1).getSomething(#)
> ```

Base from the example on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses), it seems you created `GETTERS` to retrieve the values from the JSON itself. Not really sure if this is any different.

You can try to use this online [tool](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) for better understanding as you can visually see how the indices look.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind time